# TCPDF open window with post parameters

Tags: javascript, php, tcpdf

I´m calling a tcpdf php page from javascript, like this :

```
    let wParams = "myParamsAreLarge";
    let wUrl = "www.mydomain.com/tcpdf/page.php?" + wParams;
    window.open(wUrl, "_blank", "width=500, height=400");
```

this work fine.
wParams are dinamically created so when there is a lot of data, i receive error :

Request-URI Too Long
The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.

How can i call my page.php to display tcpdf with post parameters to get the same behavour, and so avoid calling php page with get parameters ?

Regards, Juan

Answer (score 0):

The solution is : change :

```
    $pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'I');
```

to:

```
    return $pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'S');
```

then in javascript:

```
    let dataBase64 = resultData;
    let ventanaPDF = window.open("", "_blank", "width=450, height=650, nodeIntegration=no, modal");
    let contenidoFinalVentana = '<embed width=100% height=100% type="application/pdf" src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + escape(dataBase64) + '"></embed>';
    ventanaPDF.document.write(contenidoFinalVentana);
```